# return *.html.erb view as an action response - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to return a land-page that is located under "app/views/landpage.html.erb' after the user is logged out.

the code maybe something like that:

-- sessions_controller.rb -----

```
def logout
  .......
  .......

  render 'landpage'
end
```

---

In laravel we were doing something like that

```
return view('.....');
```

is there any corresponding way to do that in rails?

Comment: you could also render by naming the route.  So if you run `rake routes` you will see all routes and what their names are if they have one, and then in the logout method you could do `redirect_to landscapes_path` or whatever the name is, where that path points to that page.

Comment: Right, but is think your answer is a little bit away from what I am searching for.
I am asking if there any way to return a view from the root of  `.../views` dir ? or Is there any macro that can resolve the route to the `views` dir?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `landpage.html.erb` file in `app/views/devise/sessions` folder and it should work with your code i.e.

```rb
def logout
  .......
  .......

  render 'landpage'
end
```

If you don't have that folder, you can create it and it should work. Also, please note that if your devise model is not `User` but something else, for example, `Member` then the folder path will be `app/views/devise/members/sessions`

Comment: Yeah, I already did it, but Is it the best practice to put it within sessions dir? As you know it holds different business scope than sessions does

Comment: Ideally such views should be put in a separate folder under the views. It should not be placed directly in the views folder. So you can create a new folder `app/views/shared` and place your file there. Then from your controller, you'll use `render shared/landpage`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `render 'landpage'`, you can use the `redirect_to` method.
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to